# Django 1.8 and how to change migration order for apps

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-nose

In Django 1.8 using Postgres, how do I change the migration order? I have the following....

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "test.apps.users",
    'django_nose',
    'django_coverage',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_extensions',
]
```

and no matter what order my apps are in `oauth2_provider` gives me the error...

> **django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "users_user" does not exist**

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: oauth2_provider, staticfiles, messages, django_extensions, django_coverage, django_nose, rest_framework, common
  Apply all migrations: users, sessions, admin, auth, contenttypes
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table oauth2_provider_application
    Creating table oauth2_provider_grant
    Creating table oauth2_provider_accesstoken
    Creating table oauth2_provider_refreshtoken
    Running deferred SQL...
```

because its applying its own migrations before the apps.users table has been created.

If I removed `oauth2_provider`, apply migrations, then add back in `oauth2_provider` then apply migrations again, it works! However, there must be a way to force `test.apps.users` migrations to be created before `oauth2_provider` or anything else.

What I noticed is that inside `oauth2_provider` they have:

> migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
>   https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/migrations/0001_initial.py#L14

However, Django just ignores this and try's to apply the migration for `oauth2_provider` before my user model giving the error above error when ever I run tests and need to create a new test database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of django-oauth-toolkit do you have installed? If you installed from PyPI, try installing from the master branch on GitHub. The current version on PyPI (v0.8) does only support South migrations, but not the built-in migrations that were introduced in Django 1.7.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using the pip version which is 0.8.0 however the GitBub version is also 0.8.0 https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/__init__.py are you sure?

Comment: You are right!!!! I try the git repo version and it worked even tho the version numbers are the same! Do you know why this is?

Comment: If you look at the [commits on GitHub](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/commits/master), you will notice that the version got bumped to 0.8 on March 27th, but that there were quite a few changes since then.